# E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "=": syntax error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

я уже с ума схожу где то = не так стоит, хееелп

DatabaseHelper

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;



import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;




    public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public static String DB_NAME = "rasp.sqlite";
        private static final int SCHEMA = 1; // версия базы данных
        static final String TABLE = "myrasp";
        private static String DB_PATH;


        public SQLiteDatabase getDb() {
            return database;
        }

        public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
        public static final String COLUMN_CLASS = "class";
        public static final String COLUMN_DAY = "day";
        public static final String COLUMN_UROKID = "urok_id";
        public static final String COLUMN_UROK = "urok";
        // public static final String COLUMN_DO = "do";
        // public static final String COLUMN_STATION = "station";


        public SQLiteDatabase database;
        private Context myContext;

        public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DB_NAME, null, SCHEMA);
            this.myContext = context;
            //DB_PATH = "/data/data/student.wsiz.rzeszow.pl.myapplication/databases/";
            DB_PATH = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getAbsolutePath();
            ///DB_NAME = databaseName;
            openDataBase();


        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        }

        public void create_db() {
            boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
            if (!dbExist) {
                this.getReadableDatabase();//Создает и/или открывает базу данных
                try {
                    copyDataBase();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new Error("Error copying database!");
                }
            }

        }

        private boolean checkDataBase() {
            SQLiteDatabase checkDb = null;
            String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            try {
                checkDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
            } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            }
            //Андроид не любит утечки ресурсов, все должно закрываться
            if (checkDb != null) checkDb.close();
            return checkDb != null;
        }

        /**
         * метод проверки наличия в БД таблицы
         */
        public boolean checkTableInDB(String TABLE) {
            boolean result = false;
            Cursor cur = database.query("sqlite_master", new String[]{ " name " } , " type = ? AND name = ? " , new String[]{ " table " , TABLE}, null, null, null);
            cur.moveToLast();
            if (cur.getCount() > 0) result = true;
            cur.close();
            return result;
        }

        /**
         * метод проверки наличия поля в таблице
         */
        public boolean checkFieldInTable(String nameTable, String nameField) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                Cursor cur = database.rawQuery("PRAGMA table_info('" + nameTable + "')", null);
                cur.moveToFirst();
                while (!cur.isAfterLast()) {
                    String name = " ";
                    try {
                        name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name"));
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    }
                    if (name.equals(nameField)) {
                        result = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    cur.moveToNext();
                }
                cur.close();
                cur = null;
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            }
            return result;
        }

        private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
            // Открываем поток для чтения из уже созданной нами БД источник в assets
            InputStream externalDbStream = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
            // Путь к уже созданной пустой базе в андроиде
            String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            // Теперь создадим поток для записи в эту БД побайтно
            OutputStream localDbStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
            // Собственно, копирование
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = externalDbStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                localDbStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            // Мы будем хорошими мальчиками (девочками) и закроем потоки
            localDbStream.close();
            externalDbStream.close();
        }
        // @Override
        // public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


        /**
         * Метод получения всех данных из таблицы
         */
        public Cursor getAllData(String dbTable) {
            return database.query(dbTable, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        }

        /**
         * Метод получения данных из таблицы по условию
         */
        // public Cursor getDataByWhere(String table, String[] columns, String where, String[] where_args) {
        // return database.query(table, columns, where, where_args, null, null, null);
        // }
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }

        /** public void create_db() {
         InputStream myInput = null;
         OutputStream myOutput = null;
         try {
         File file = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
         if (!file.exists()) {
         this.getReadableDatabase();
         myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

         String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
         myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
         byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
         int length;
         while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
         myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
         }

         myOutput.flush();
         myOutput.close();
         myInput.close();
         }
         } catch (IOException ex) {

         }
         }**/

        /**
         * Метод открытия БД
         */
        public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
            String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            if (database == null) {
                create_db();
                database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
            }
            return database;
        }

        // public void open() throws SQLException {
        //  String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        // database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
        //      SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        // }

        @Override
        public synchronized void close() {
            if (database != null) {
                database.close();
            }
            super.close();
        }


    }
```

Main2Activity

```
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.TextView;






public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String classID, tabID;Bundle b;

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        Toolbar toolbar =  findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        classID = bundle.getString("classID");
        toolbar.setTitle("Класс:" + classID);


        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main2, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */


    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            //return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);

            switch (position){

                case 0:
                    BlankFragment1 bf1 = new BlankFragment1();
                    b = new Bundle();
                    b.putString("tabID","1");
                    return bf1;
                case 1:
                    BlankFragment2 bf2 =new BlankFragment2();
                    b = new Bundle();
                    b.putString("tabID","2");
                    return bf2;
                case 2:
                    BlankFragment3 bf3 = new BlankFragment3();
                    b = new Bundle();
                    b.putString("tabID","3");
                    return bf3;
                case 3:
                    BlankFragment4 bf4 = new BlankFragment4();
                    b = new Bundle();
                    b.putString("tabID","4");
                    return bf4;
                case 4:
                    BlankFragment5 bf5 = new BlankFragment5();
                    b = new Bundle();
                    b.putString("tabID","5");
                    return bf5;

                case 5:
                    BlankFragment6 bf6 = new BlankFragment6();
                    b = new Bundle();
                    b.putString("tabID","5");
                    return bf6;
                case 6:
                    BlankFragment7 bf7 = new BlankFragment7();
                    b = new Bundle();
                    b.putString("tabID","5");
                    return bf7;
                default:
                    return  null;

            }

        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 7;
        }
}}
```

Blank_fragment1

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;




/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class BlankFragment1 extends ListFragment {
    String classId;
    SimpleCursorAdapter userAdapter;
    DatabaseHelper sqlHelper;
    Cursor userCursor;
    ListView mList;


    public BlankFragment1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank_fragment1,container,false);
        mList=(ListView) rootview.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        return  rootview;
    }

    @Override

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle bundle = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
        classId = bundle.getString("classID");
        sqlHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        sqlHelper.create_db();
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        try {
            sqlHelper.openDataBase();
            userCursor = sqlHelper.database.rawQuery("select * from " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE + " where class = " + classId + "and day = 1", null);
            String[] headers = new String[]{DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_UROK};
            userAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.item, userCursor, headers, new int[]{R.id.uroki}, 0);
            mList.setAdapter(userAdapter);
        }
        catch (SQLException ex){}
    }
    }
```

Comment: если у вас выскакивает сообщение об ошибке - посмотрите в логах, на какую строчку оно указывает. Там ваш "="

Comment: он указывает на путь к апликации student.wsiz.rzeszow.pl.myapplication

Comment: Приложите к вопросу стектрейс с ошибкой. Вероятность того, что вам ответят (а вопрос не закроют), значительно вырастет

Comment: `"and day = 1"` -  здесь не хватает пробела в начале

Comment: да да спасибо большое пробела не было !!! Спасибо